# How can I unlock my phone that has been locked via windowsphone.com and encountered an error?

Tags: lock-screen, find-my-phone

I was just testing **Find My Phone** on [windowsphone.com](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/How-to/wp7/basics/find-a-lost-phone). I locked it and entered password as 1234, windowsphone.com displayed a message that it cannot lock at the moment and asked me to try again later but the phone got locked and asked me to enter a password. I tried 1234 but it doesn't work. I tried to lock it again from windowsphone.com with password as 1111, but my phone can't be unlocked with this either.

How can I unlock my phone?

Comment: Have you tried rebooting it via holding Lock+VolDn? Is your phone normally locked with a different password, and have you tried that one?

Comment: I just restored it back to a previous state.

Comment: @Takneik *How* did you restore it to it's previous state? It would be helpful for others having the same problem in the future, if you add your solution as an answer (heck, people may even vote for it, earning you reputation!)...

Comment: Have you tried to use the pin you phone uses instead the one provided in the website?

Comment: @VitorCanova Dumb me didn't try that :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restored it via Zune to a 2-month-old backup.

Here's the detailed procedure to [Restore a backup to your phone](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp7/basics/restore-a-backup-to-my-phone).

> #### Restore a backup using your computer
>
> 1. Make note of any changes you made since your last update so you'll know what to do later to set up your phone the way you want.
> 2. Ensure you're installing the backup from your primary computer, where you installed the original update.
> 3. Get your phone and primary computer ready. To learn more, see [Make room on my computer for phone updates](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp7/basics/make-room-on-your-computer-for-phone-updates) and [Make room on my phone to update it](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp7/basics/make-room-on-your-phone-to-update-it).
> 4. Connect your phone to your primary computer using the USB cable that came with your phone.
> 5. In the Zune software, click *Settings* -> *Phone* -> *Update*.
> 6. Click *Restore*.
> 7. Follow the on-screen instructions in the Zune software.

After you've completed these steps, your phone will be restored to its state from the most recent available restore point. You can see this date to the right of the *Restore* button.

Comment: Can you add a little more detail on how you did this so someone else who comes across this question knows how to do this?

Comment: You have Windows Device Recovery Tool why you use Zune???

Comment: @GlacialMan It was a wp7 device, this tool works on 8+

Comment: @caschw done! :)

Answer (score 2):

The best way to restore to previous state is to use the WP8 built-in feature for "settings backup" during the first time the phone is turned on.

The settings are stored in Microsoft cloud and tied back to your MSA/Live account. After you perform a hard reset or just get a new device you select to restore last settings and in couple of minutes you have your previous phone state back.